# Are Palestinians out of the Ubuntu App Showdown Contest?

Tags: application-development, canonical

Canonical does not support shipment to Palestine. Are we (Palestinians) out of the Ubuntu App Showdown Contest because of that?

**Edit**

I contact canonical shipment team, and they told me they don't support shipment to Palestine, and also I tried to buy some stuff from there website, but i couldn't cause of that reason. and here the exact words in recieved from the canonical shipment team: "At the present time we do not ship to your region but hope to do so in the future.

Answer (score 3):

### Don't worry you can participate

Ubuntu app showdown contest is not limited to some particular countries. So you can participate. I can't find any restriction for Canonical to ship to Palestine.

Comment: I contact canonical shipment team, and they told me they don't support shipment to Palestine, and also I tried to buy some stuff from there website, but i couldn't cause of that reason.

and here the exact words in recieved from the canonical shipment team:
"At the present time we do not ship to your region but hope to do so in the future. "